# Changing Provisioning Profile in Expo from Terminal

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I made a mistake and used the wrong provisioning profile while running `expo build:ios` via [this tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html). There doesn't seem to be any handy documentation as to how to update it—just a lot of questions from people in my same boat.

[Here is a screenshot of the related error.](https://screencast.com/t/grDFWiosia)

I just need need to remove the old profile and add the new one. Is that a command for that?

Note: I am not using xCode—just Terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The correct way to change the credentials is to run `expo build:ios -c`. There is no need to use fastlane and sigh. Running `-c` at the end removes the current credentials and allows you to enter new ones. H[ere is a screenshot of the outcome.](https://screencast.com/t/MhNhWqrY4JW) I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 7):

The current accepted answer works because it clears all the credentials expo generates.

Actually, if you just want to remove provisioning profile only, then you could do

```
expo build:ios --clear-provisioning-profile
```

Use case for this command is, for example when you built the app but got "Missing Push Notification Entitlement", what you'd want to regenerate is the provisioning profile only.  (I found this option while I was investigating the cause of this error, at following forum: https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-fix-missing-push-notification-entitlement/19615 )

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using fastlane and sigh

Here the docs: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/#resign

Good luck!

Comment: I'm baffled that there isn't a way to do this within Expo and that I'd need a third party for it. I will look into this. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eas credentials` command to delete your credentials. Note, this only removes those credentials from Expo's servers, it does not delete them from your Apple Developer Console. This means that to fully delete your credentials (let's say, because you want a new push notification key but you already have 2), you'll need to do so from the Apple Developer Console.

Then run `eas build -p ios` to generate new credentials again.

learn more here [expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/app-credentials/)